# how to mock an exception thrown by a class' __construct

Tags: php, phpunit

Imagine a class A istantiating a class B. 
I'm trying to write a test for class A and mock the behavior of B.

B could throw some exception when istantiated, and that's what I want to mock with phpunit so as to test A properly.

Is it possible to mock the magic function `__construct` in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Not with PHPUnit's mocking capability.  You would need to redefine the class in your test so that B's `__construct` throws an exception.  Except that this could cause errors to be thrown later when you are trying to test B or you want B to actually be constructed due to the class already being defined.  These difficulties are a code smell that your code is not optimally designed.

Rather what you should be doing is passing B into A's `__construct` method.  This is Dependency Injection.  So you would create a mock of B and pass it in to A.  This is clearer because if B's `__construct` throws an exception, this is a problem with B and not A.  In general, you should avoid using `new` within your objects and instead pass them in (except in the case of Factory classes).

Comment: I totally agree that these difficulties are a code smell, since I was working on legacy code and I was mixing two designs. basically, what I'm accustomed to do is creatinv ValueObjects that check their values when instantiated, otherwise they return a parameterException. But in this case all the project is using the constructor just for instantiating and injecting the dependencies. If I'm stick to that, I don't have any issue with testing my code.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion you have badly design your classes and a test case of a class must be always related to the class itself: you should not test a class B in a test for class A.

PHPUnit is not able to implement a test of this type but you could use another library ([Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/)), that helps you to test this kind of dependencies. With Mockery you can do something like:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('MyClass');
$mock->shouldReceive('name_of_method_1')
    ->once()
    ->with($arg1)
    ->andReturn('return value');
```

Comment: this is the practical straightforward solution. Could you specify that phpunit does not allow it and you have to use another library so that I can accept it as the answer?

Also, Schleis's answer deserves a mention: if you bump into this kind of problem your could could be not well designed.